# Doctrine LifecycleEventArgs return Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, listener

I'm trying to work with doctrine event in a symfony project,
following the symfony doc I have this code

```
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();


    if (!$entity instanceof Rubrique) {
        return;
    }

    $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
    // do some stuff
}
```

The problem is that `$entity` is not the expected object `Rubrique` but an instance of `Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry` maybe because `Rubrique` is `Loggable`. How can I access to my entity for manipulate it as I want ?
Thanks

Comment: `postPersist` should be called twice. Once for `Rubrique`and once for `LogEntry`. Have you tested that?

Answer (score 1):

This event listener is a ["generic" one](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) and not an [doctrine entity listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html)

This means that the event is raised for each entity persisted: if you have a relation between `Rubrique` and `LogEntry`, than is possible that you're checking only for the "first" of them being "postPersisted".

If you need a specific listener only for that kind of entity, think about using doctrine entity listener (linked above).

Moreover remember that "generic" listener will listen (or will be subscribed) for events of **every** entity (so, basically, it could be invoked a lot of times) wheres doctrine entity listener not.

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes I need this event for all of my entities.My question was how can I retrieve my entity because  getEntity() methode returns Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry and not my entity

Comment: @M.Smaïne as said, `getEntity` will return different types of entities: is up to you verify what entity is and, if  `Rubrique` was not flushed, check why isn't flushed or retrieve it from other objects.

Comment: I give you more details maybe you'll help me again. I develop a saas application. Every entity have a many to one relationship with an Entity Client. I would to set the client after every add Entity action. This is why I used Doctrine listener... Am I wrong ?

Comment: @M.Smaïne it is a way of doing this. you'll never take off doctrine from your project but, if you do, you'll lose all this behavior. On the other hand if you don't want this "dependency" you should create from scratch something to reach this out. It's an hard choice; in our project we have chosen to follow doctrine listeners because project was already "committed" with doctrine

Comment: Many thanks. I was wrong, I thought getEntity return the object instance flushed but It return the class. So I have to retrieve the object instance and set the client. Thank for your help @DonCallisto